# How to update custom fields using the wp_insert_post() function?

Tags: php, posts, custom-field, post-meta, wp-insert-post

The WordPress function is used for submitting data programatically. Standard fields to submit to incude the content, excerpt, title, date and many more.

What there is no documentation for is how to submit to a custom field. I know it is possible with the `add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);` function.

But, how to include that into the standard `wp_insert_post` function?

```
<?php 
$my_post = array(
     'post_title' => $_SESSION['booking-form-title'],
     'post_date' => $_SESSION['cal_startdate'],
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_type' => 'booking',
  );
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
  ?>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), it returns the post ID of the post you just created.

If you combine that with the following function `__update_post_meta` (a custom function I acquired from this site and adapted a bit)

```
/**
  * Updates post meta for a post. It also automatically deletes or adds the value to field_name if specified
  *
  * @access     protected
  * @param      integer     The post ID for the post we're updating
  * @param      string      The field we're updating/adding/deleting
  * @param      string      [Optional] The value to update/add for field_name. If left blank, data will be deleted.
  * @return     void
  */
public function __update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value = '' )
{
    if ( empty( $value ) OR ! $value )
    {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name );
    }
    elseif ( ! get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name ) )
    {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
    }
    else
    {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
    }
}
```

You'll get the following:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $_SESSION['booking-form-title'],
    'post_date' => $_SESSION['cal_startdate'],
    'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'booking',
);
$the_post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );


__update_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'my-custom-field', 'my_custom_field_value' );
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Could you possibly give me an idea on the implantation. IE. which but of code goes where. Many Thanks

Comment: Nicely done. The second code block replaces yours, the function values is the custom field key/value pair. Put the function either at the top of the script, or in a separate .php file included at the top of the script.

Comment: As a note, I do use OOP so that's the reason for the `public` modifier in front of "function". If you're including the function itself without putting it into a class, you don't need to add `public`

Comment: Hello Zack, Aendrew and Philip. Everything is working beautifully however I tried to apply it to a query as well to no avail. I don't quite see why. Here is the link since you all know how the initial custom field new post worked I thought you might see my error. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8622/wp-insert-post-php-function-dynamically-generated-custom-fields

Comment: @Zack - Nice answer. But I would tend to shy away from using leading underscores in function names if only because names with leading underscores tend to be used by platform developers when they want to create _"reserved"_ or _(pseudo) "hidden"_ functions so people seeing those might think they are platform functions, or worse they might conflict with a future WordPress core function. Just a thought.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: At first, I originally started using "__" for protected functions within a class, but then changed the structure of my plugin to where the function needed to be public. I also would've named it simply "update_post_meta" but that would've definitely conflicted with WordPress' core functions. So I didn't know what to name it :(

Comment: @Zack - Maybe `zacks_update_post_meta()`? :) The other issue I didn't mention with leading underscores is that someone else equally creative may use the same convention in a plugin and thus conflict with yours. BTW, did you know that `update_post_meta()` adds if it doesn't exist?  `add_post_meta()` is only needed when you want to add duplicate keys.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: I originally found the function elsewhere on this site, liked it, and refactored it just because I'm like that. I also figured `update_post_meta()` did that already, but couldn't be sure. When I found the function, I jumped to conclusions.

Comment: @Zack - Hey learning WordPress is a journey. I figure I still have at least 50% more of that journey left, if not a lot more!

Comment: I can't add an answer, as I don't have reputation on wordpress.stackexchange. As of today there is a new method, you can simply put in an array into wp_insert_post as: meta_input => array(key=>value)

Answer (score 17):

You can simple add the 'add_post_meta' after the 'wp_insert_post'

```
<?php 
$my_post = array(
     'post_title' => $_SESSION['booking-form-title'],
     'post_date' => $_SESSION['cal_startdate'],
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_type' => 'booking',
  );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

add_post_meta($post_id, 'META-KEY-1', 'META_VALUE-1', true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'META-KEY-2', 'META_VALUE-2', true);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add 'meta_input' element on the post parameters as an array of post meta values keyed by their post meta key

```
<?php 

$my_post = array(
     'post_title' => $_SESSION['booking-form-title'],
     'post_date' => $_SESSION['cal_startdate'],
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_type' => 'booking',

    'meta_input' => array(
      'your_custom_meta_field_name' => $_SESSION['your_custom_meta_field_value']
    )
  );
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `save_post` filter, then call `add_post_meta` in your filter function.

Comment: Unhelpful. $post->ID is not available to wp_insert_post_data, which is necessary for creating custom fields.

Comment: @aendrew `save_post` action is at the very end of the function, it has post's ID and object passed to it, answer is sound.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was edited, Rarst. Regardless, it makes sense now.

Comment: @aendrew ah, sorry - didn't notice that

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use it with wp_insert_post();.

The reason is because of how WP stores the two data types. Posts are stored in one big monolithic table with a dozen different columns (wp_posts); custom fields are stored in a simpler, 4-column table (wp_postmeta) comprised mainly of a meta key and value, associated with a post.

Consequently, you can't really store custom fields until you have the post ID.

Try this:

```
function myplugin_insert_customs($pid){

    $customs = array(
    'post_id' => $pid,
    'meta_key' => 'Your meta key',
    'meta_value' => 'Your meta value',
    );

    add_post_meta($customs);

}

add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_insert_customs', 99);
```

This codex post helped -- it's kinda the opposite of what you're doing (i.e., deleting a DB row upon post deletion): http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

Comment: In that case the only way out I can see is to use a session, would that be correct.

Comment: Nah; I'm guessing your plugin is trying to insert custom fields at the same time a post is saved, right? I think what you need to do is hook into WP after the post is saved, grab the post's new ID number, then supply that to add_post_meta(); to create the CFs. I'll update my answer in a second with some code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By the way its not a plugin. I wrote it so we can customise it as much as needed. (but don't take that to mean I'm any good with php, just trial and error)

Comment: It's a theme, then? Only real difference is you'd put that in functions.php, in that case.