# WP Insert Post and then go to post

Tags: php, posts

After an WP_insert_posts array has been executed how do I then redirect the browser to that post.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array( 'your', 'args', 'here' ) );

$link = get_permalink( $post_id );

wp_redirect( $link );

die();
```

Comment: Also need to `die()` right after `wp_redirect()`.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .......... Zack I think it is not working because we are not using the $post_id. we are using  $the_post_id thanks to your brilliant script from a few days ago. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/wp-insert-post-php-function-and-custom-fields