# How do I use wp_query for WordPress search?

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, search, post-meta

I would like to create a custom search form to search posts based on the values of about 4 custom fields. I tried using wp_query to achieve this but so far my biggest problem is that the I don't get any results when searching for data in custom fields - even for data that I am sure exists. Also, I can't figure out how to remove the normal WordPress "keyword" search box and use just my four combo boxes.

Here is the code from my search.php file: http://pastie.org/private/jhgsmaolvjyswyhsfphlfa
 
and here's the code from my searchform.php:  pastie.org/private/o3hrtqajh8hbkiht1nyoba

Here is an image of the form layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ncg.png

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP insert post PHP function and Custom Fields](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/wp-insert-post-php-function-and-custom-fields)

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine your search query with a new WP Query...

That would be something like this, on your search.php

```
<?php

global $wp_query; // get the global object

$thesearch = get_search_query(); // get the string searched

// merge them with one or several meta_queries to meet your demand
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 
   'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'field_to_seach',
        'value' => $thesearch,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
    ));
query_posts( $args ); // alter the main query to include your custom parameters

?>
```

Comment: Someone down voted this and I'd really like to know why, since this is something I use on a regular basis. If you care to explain, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: Hi Moraleida, thanks for the answer. I'll surely try it out. I don't know who down-voted the answer, but I can't even vote because my reputation is low as a newbie here.
I'll try out the code that you've suggested.
My search form has 5 drop-down fields with values for those 5 custom fields. Should I just use the form as-is, with you code above?

Comment: I wasn't talking about you @3ph, not to worry :).

Comment: About the code usage, it depends on what really you need to achieve. Try it out with one custom field as is. If it works, then just add another 4 of the `array('key' => 'field_to_seach', 'value' => $thesearch, 'compare' => 'IN')` parts. Drop in if you need more help.

Comment: Hi @moraleida, I just tried it but I'm not getting any results from custom fields in the search.
Here's the code from my search.php file: http://pastie.org/private/jhgsmaolvjyswyhsfphlfa and here's the code from searchform.php: http://pastie.org/private/o3hrtqajh8hbkiht1nyoba

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I guess it's because there're much better approaches to this, like using the `posts_clauses` and such pre-query filters, which will save you some queries.

Answer (score 0):

You always can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) or [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) hooks.

Here you have an example of using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to exclude some posts from search results: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_Pages_from_Search_Results

It's better solution, because you won't make another, redundant SQL query.