# save content in to wordpress wp_post table of database

Tags: database

i write code to get content from other site.

now I want save content in to wp_post of wordpress database..

date .. content.. titile ,..

[wp_insert function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)
 [wp_publish function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post)

thise my php function..

```
      function writeMsg(){
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `wp_farsc`');



    if($result && mysql_num_rows ($result)> 0){
  $data = null;
  $data.= '<table border="2px" cellspacing="5px" width="100%">'.PHP_EOL;
  $data.= '<tr bgcolor="yellow"><th>سکه</th><th>قیمت انلاین</th><th>تغییر قیمت</th><th>کمترین</th><th>بیشترین</th><th>زمان بروز رسانی</th></tr>'.PHP_EOL;

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

     $data .='<tr>';
     $data .= '<td>'.$row ['titile'].'</td>';
     $data .='<td>'.$row ['liveprice'].'</td>';
     $data .='<td>'.$row ['changing'].'</td>';
     $data .= '<td>'.$row ['lowest'].'</td>';
     $data .= '<td>'.$row ['topest'].'</td>';
     $data .= '<td>'.$row ['time'].'</td>';
     $data .='</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
  }

  }

 mysql_close();
 return $data;
 }
```

Comment: first of all, you shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated and will eventually be removed from future php versions. WordPress has the [`wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for querying other databases. as for your question, have you tried using `wp_insert_post`?

Comment: can you write example code to save content in wordpress with wp_insert_post function?

Comment: Why Codex examples of `wp_insert_post` usage doesn't satisfy you, @Mortzea?

Comment: This post will help you. First and second answers are useful.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/wp-insert-post-php-function-and-custom-fields